# some png images not load in IE10

Tags: firefox, png, internet-explorer-10

I am working with a webpage that compatible to IE10. In IE10 some png images are loaded perfectly. but some images are not load(looks like a broken image). But every thing work in FF19. why this happening? any solution for this?

```
<BODY>
  <img src = "aaa/Test1.png" />
  <img src = "aaa/Test2.png" />
  <img src = "aaa/Test3.png" />
  <img src = "aaa/Test4.png" />
</BODY>
```

UPDATE :

The problem occurs only when i open the html file locally. If i open with domain images are loaded. Am so confused. Please some one tell me why this happening?

Comment: can you show some code or link to the images?

Comment: <BODY>
 <img src = "aaa/Test1.png" />
 <img src = "aaa/Test2.png" />
 <img src = "aaa/Test3.png" />
 <img src = "aaa/Test4.png" /> 
 </BODY>

Comment: I tested in both FF and IE10. Test3.png is broken in IE10.

Comment: One of the following is the issue. A.) the cAsE sENsiTIvity of your path is incorrect and some browsers/servers care more than others. B.) The image isn't a PNG image type (and again some browsers handle this error for you, rendering a JPG "as" a PNG etc.) C.) The image is partially corrupt and IE is having issues with the corrupt part. D.) the image might support advanced options that IE can't handle. or something else that is similar.  I'd recommend posting the image online for others to check out or re-exporting the image from whatever tool you used to create it.

Answer (score 2):

So I was having this error as well and my fix was very obnoxious. PNG and JPG files are very similar, in fact they are so similar that you can simply change the file extension and most image viewers and browsers can render the image properly.

My problem was that I had some native .png and a single native .jpg. For some reason we decided that we wanted all of the files to .png so we simply changed the .jpg extension to a .png extension instead of saving the image properly in say photoshop. This worked great as almost every browser was able to decipher what was going on except for of course IE. This was causing some great confusion amongst our team members until we found out what happened.

I would try to open the image that is failing in PS and save it as .png. This is what fixed our problem.

Hope it helps